# symfony phpunit not receive expected value

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, symfony

I'm trying to test a simple function inside my service in Symfony.

The function get the post value if exist and set a multidimensional array.
this is my function inside a service:

```
public function setValue(Request $request)
    {
        for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
            for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){
                if(($request->request->get('cell_' . $i . '_' . $j) != null){
                    $value = $request->request->get('cell_' . $i . '_' . $j);
                    echo('Value: ' . $value . '|');
                    $this->tiles[$i][$j] = $value;
                }
                else{
                    $this->tiles[$i][$j] = '0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my part of test (not all test but a simple part)

```
public function testGetSatusGameEnd()
{
    $this->requestMock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->requestMock->request = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->requestMock->request->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('cell_1_1')
        ->will($this->returnValue('1'));

    $board = new Board();
    $board->setValue($this->requestMock);

    var_dump($board->getArrayResult());
}
```

In this case I set only a cell in theory with value 1 but when I dump all the result I get this

```
array(3) {
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [1] =>
    NULL
    [2] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    [1] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(3) {
    [1] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Because inside `cell_1_1` there is an empty value I check, but I'm expected to have `1` not empty!
How can I return `1` inside `cell_1_1` , What is the error of my mock?

Thanks

Comment: Is the missing `)` in the first if block just an error from copying over? I was trying to recreate this and this was the first thing I noticed.

Comment: yes sorry, it was an error from copying over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `get` is returning null is because the index for `at()` has already been incremented by the first call (in the if statement).

I found some useful information on [this article](https://addshore.com/2015/08/misled-by-phpunit-at-method/) about it being misleading.

You might not want to bother with `expects()` and `at()` at all, since it doesn't really reflect the behaviour of an actual parameter bag, which would return the same regardless of when it was called.

You could use the mock objects with a callback to return '1' only when the name is cell_1_1, like this:

```
$this
  ->requestMock
  ->request
  ->method('get')
  ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($name) {
            return $name === 'cell_1_1' ? '1' : null;
  }));
```

Or you could just use the Symfony request itself and same yourself a lot of complication :-)

Sample code for test using real Request:

```
    $request = new Request([], ['cell_1_1' => '1']);
    $board = new Board();
    $board->setValue($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not filling index `0` of the array.

Take a look at your loops:

```
...
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    for($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){
...
```

Both start from index `1` instead of index `0`. That way the first array-element won't never be set and that is why it is `null`.

You have to change your `for` this way.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
```

Comment: I have tried, same error, this solutiuon doesn't work